# What is the meaning of 'LocalDb'?

Tags: sql-server-2012-express

I learned is that in order to connect to SQL Server Express 2012 I have to use the instance name "(LocalDb)\v11.0".

Is this localDb a special db for local developmnents or is it the exact equivalent to Sql Express 2008 but with a different name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are different in the fact that SQL Server Express runs as a service, and that localdb runs on-demand in user-mode. As far as creating databases/inserting data/selecting data then I believe they are functionally identical.

Comment: Hi Paul. But what if I was interested in the service version of sql server express from VS2012, do I have to install Sql Server Express 2008 also?

Comment: You can install Sql Server Express 2012 without installing Sql Server Express 2008

Comment: Hi Paul, this Sql Server express 2012 comes with VS2012, which I have already installed, but what if I wanted to use the database as a service in the future, do I have to install sql server express 2008 also?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you keep asking if SQL Server 2008 Express is equivalent to the SQL Server 2012 Express edition installed with Visual Studio 2012.

Answer: they are completely different: 2008, 2008R2, 2012.

More importantly, SQL Express is also different than running your (LocalDB) inside Visual Studio 2012 using the new SSDT SQL Server Database Project.  As another person said, it runs only when you run your code.

There's a lot of information out there already:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/06/06/getting-started-with-localdb-debugging-using-ssdt.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms246989.aspx